# Need particular text as output from a text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a text file named `result.txt` which contains,

```
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'recovery' (18502 KB)...
OKAY [  0.669s]
writing 'recovery'...
FAILED [  0.138s]
finished. total time: 0.807s
```

I need exact output of the particular word "FAILED" as a output (from the fifth line)

I'm running the program,

```
@echo off
cls
for /f "skip=5 tokens=1" %%a in (result.txt) do set word2=%%a
echo %word2%
pause
```

But, I'm not getting the output which I need.. Please help guys..
I need `FAILED` word(string) as a output.

Comment: Based solely on your `results.txt` file, should you not be `skip`ing 4? `For /F "Skip=4" %%A In (result.txt) Do Set "word2=%%A"`

Comment: what do you really want: a) check, if there is `FAILED` exactly in the fifth line b) check, if there is `FAILED` somewhere in the file c) check if it's on line 5 or later, d) check, *what* status is in the fifth line ?

Answer (score 0):

as Compo already noted, you need to skip **4** lines, if you need the fifth...

But there is another issue. Your loop continues and as a result, always gets you the first token of the very last line. To avoid it, use:

```
@echo off
set "word2="
for /f "skip=4 tokens=1" %%a in (result.txt) do if defined word2 set "word2=%%a"
echo %word2%
pause
```

or

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=4 tokens=1" %%a in (result.txt) do (
  set "word2=%%a"
  goto :next
)
:next
echo %word2%
pause
```

Both techniques break the loop after the first pass.

Answer (score 0):

you could parse your result.txt file with the `find` command:

`find "FAILED" result.txt`

or use `type` with pipe to avoid the `----result.txt` output:

`type result.txt|find "FAILED" /i`